# Extension of a group action beyond the boundary

Tags: differential-topology, group-actions

Let $M$ be a compact manifold with boundary and suppose a compact group $G$ acts on it. Can one always extend the action beyond the boundary? More precisely, does there always exist a $G$-manifold with boundary $N$, with $\dim M=\dim N$,  and a $G$-equivariant embedding of $M$ into the interior of $N$?

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking for a topological action, then it would seem you can just double $M$ along the boundary. I am not sure this works in the smooth category..

Comment: You can always take a metric such that the boundary has a collar neighbourhood which looks like a product. You have to make sure first that the action of $G$ respects the product structure. If you average over $G$, the action will be by isometries. Then you can double.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Good point!

Comment: @IgorRivin Topological extension is easy to construct. But I need a smooth extension.

Comment: @MaximBraverman Sebastian tells you how to tweak a topological extension to a smooth extension.

Comment: @SebastianGoette I think to take the double it is not enough to know that the action of $G$ preserves the product structure. Of course, if $G$ action is a product, then the action on the double is smooth. But in general you have a family $\phi_t:G\to Diff(N)$ of actions and the action on the collar $N\times[0,1)$ is given by $g\cdot (y,t)= (\phi_t(g)(y),t)$. When you extend it to the double, the action on the double of the collar will be $g\cdot (y,t)= (\phi_{|t|}(g)(y),t)$ for $t\in (-1,1)$. Why is it smooth at $t=0$?

Comment: @MaximBraverman You are right. Action by isometries is good if you can make the boundary totally geodesic, but this is, in general, not possible.

Comment: @IgorRivin Actually, I don't understand why this construction gives a smooth action even if the boundary is totally geodesic. Suppose that  a neighborhood of the the boundary is isometric to the product $N\times[0,1)$ and the group action is given by $\phi_t$ as in my comment to Sebastian, where each $\phi_t$ defines an isometry of $N$. Why this action extends to  a smooth action beyond the boundary?

Comment: @MaximBraverman I am trying to think of an example where $\phi_t$ is not conjugate to a constant action (this is the case I had in mind - respecting the product structure means mapping $\{y\}\times[0,1)$ to $\{g(y)\}\times[0,1)$ in my terminology). Do you have such an example where $G$ is compact?

Comment: @SebastianGoette I don't have an example. I would not be surprised if it is always the case. But I can not prove it.

Comment: @MaximBraverman Then I suggest that you put that discussion into your question. Maybe someone else has a solution.

Comment: @SebastianGoette I found a paper of Palais "Equivalence of nearby differentiable actions of a compact group" which shows that any two actions which are closed to each other are conjugated. Moreover, given a continuous family of actions, one can find a continuous family of conjugations.  It is not clear to me from his proof whether one can find a smooth family of conjugations. However, I found a much more recent paper of Kankaanrinta, which proves all what I need, see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the action can be extended. It immediately follows from the *equivariant collaring  theorem* proven in the paper Kankaanrinta, Marja Equivariant collaring, tubular neighbourhood and gluing theorems for proper Lie group actions. Algebr. Geom. Topol. 7 (2007), 1–27.

Let me formulate the equivariant collaring theorem.  An *equivariant collar* of $\partial M$ is a smooth $G$-equivariant embedding
$$f:\partial{}M\times [0,\infty)\to M,$$ 
such that $f(x,0)=x$ for all $x\in \partial M$. The equivariant collaring theorem states that given a smooth proper action of a (possibly non-compact) Lie group an manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial{}M$, the boundary has an equivariant collar.

To extend the action of $G$ "beyond the boundary" we now simply consider the manifold $M\cup_{\partial M}(\partial M\times(-1,0])$ and  extend the action of $G$ to $\partial M\times(-1,0]$ by
$$g\cdot (x,t)\ := \ (g\cdot x,t).$$